# Boot Ubuntu 22.04.1 from a USB drive without erasing disk

Tags: partitioning, usb

I use mac and was wanting to run Ubuntu but not have it replace mac os. I downloaded the ISO file to an external USB drive and using VMware fusion on my computer I tried running Ubuntu. I was going through the installation menu and was told: **This computer currently has no detected operating systems. What would you like to do?** and given the options to either: a)**Erase disk and Install Ubuntu** or b)**Something else**. I was wondering if anyone knows what I should do as I would preferably not like to wipe my USB disk and am really worried that the first option may wipe mac os from my computer. Any advice?

*edit* thank you all for your help I've decided not to install ubuntu at the moment.

Comment: `Something else` will let you choose location of bootloader, partitions to install to and partitions to format. Other than, that I have never actually touched a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Following this usually helps:
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
You can also partition your disk:
[/guide/disk-utility/](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/disk-utility/dskutl14027/mac#:%7E:text=before%20you%20begin.-,In%20the%20Disk%20Utility%20app%20on%20your%20Mac%2C%20select%20a,Space%20Sharing%20dialog%2C%20click%20Partition.)

Can provide hardware and software version information please?

Answer (score 1):

BE CAREFUL not to wipe your laptop hard drive!!! from your question it is not clear which drive you are operating on. STOP until you are absolutely sure which drive you are operating on.

IF you are installing onto a VMware virtual instance inside your mac, then VMware is creating a virtual environment with a virtual disk drive. The VMware virtual drive will take up space on your laptop hard drive- it will look like a big file. You can safely install the new operating system inside your VMware system because it's just a virtual drive inside your laptop hard drive. You can safely delete the virtual system files anytime you want to start over. Virtualization is fun, educational and useful. As long as you are truly installing ubuntu into a vmware virtual machine, your easiest option is **a)Erase disk and Install Ubuntu**. And the great thing about virtual machines is that if you screw it up you can just delete it off your mac and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The *point* of VMWare is to provide a virtual machine. This includes virtual hard drives. There's generally two ways you can test Ubuntu in a VM:

- Boot from a live medium
- Install Ubuntu in the VM.

Neither option will be destructive to anything on the host computer, but may be destructive if you recycle a VM.

There is at no stage a need to write the installer or live medium to a physical device; [vmware.com has an article detailing how to install from ISO images](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1002).